Bitbucket server api for committing file to branch failing with error Bitbucket: ‘pbord3’ != Commit: ‘lastName, firstName’
I am using below API to commit file to a branch using API.
PUT /api/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path}

I am facing below error -
Bitbucket: ‘pbord3’ != Commit: ‘lastName, firstName’
Committer name in your git user.name is not matching with bitbucket user slug. Please make sure you have mentioned correct network id under your git user.name
My .gitconfig file in local has user name as - ‘pbord3’ , and it matches with bitbucket user slug which is also ‘pbord3’.
on file commits , my name is shown as ‘lastName, firstName’
I am not sure what to change and where to look at? kind of stuck at this place. Any support here would be really helpful
